# EF returning different values than query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

So I just came across this very odd scenario and was wondering if anyone might know what the problem is.  I have the following EF Linq query.

```
var hierarchies = (from hierarchy in ctx.PolygonHierarchyViews
                   where hierarchy.DashboardId == dashboardId
                   select hierarchy);
```

When I inspect that query in the debugger it shows the following SQL

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[DashboardId] AS [DashboardId], 
[Extent1].[CurrentId] AS [CurrentId], 
[Extent1].[PolygonTypeId] AS [PolygonTypeId], 
[Extent1].[DisplayName] AS [DisplayName], 
[Extent1].[ParentId] AS [ParentId]
FROM [dbo].[PolygonHierarchyView] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[DashboardId] = @p__linq__0
```

If I run that in SQL Server Management Studio substituding `@p__linq__0` with the value of `dashboardId`.  I get these results.

```
DashboardId     CurrentId  Type  Name       ParentId
4               5          1     Region     NULL
4               6          2     Market     NULL
4               7          3     SubMarket  6
4               8          4     ZipCode    7
4               6          2     Market     5
4               7          3     SubMarket  6
4               8          4     ZipCode    7
```

However the results from iterating the EF query are as follows.

```
DashboardId     CurrentId  Type  Name       ParentId
4               5          1     Region     NULL
4               6          2     Market     NULL
4               7          3     SubMarket  6
4               8          4     ZipCode    7
4               6          2     Market     NULL
4               7          3     SubMarket  6
4               8          4     ZipCode    7
```

Notice that the fifth row has a `ParentId` of `NULL` instead of 5.  This is how I worked around the problem.

```
var hierarchies = (from hierarchy in ctx.PolygonHierarchyViews
                   where hierarchy.DashboardId == dashboardId
                   group hierarchy by hierarchy.ParentId into grp
                   select grp).AsEnumerable();
```

The odd thing here is that this results in a `IGrouping` with a `Key` value of 5, but the `ParentId` of the single object in that group is `null`.

I'm attempting to creat a `lookup` from that query and wanted to just do

```
var lookup = hierarchies.ToLookup(h => h.ParentId);
```

But since the actually `ParentId` doesn't seem to always have the correct value and I have to do the group by I end up having to do the following

```
var lookup = hierarchies.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => new { x.Key, View = y }))
                        .ToLookup(h => h.Key, h => h.View);
```

To make matters even stranger, if I remove the `AsEnumerable` from the end of the query before doing the `SelectMany` and `ToLookup` it will still result in the entity that should have a `ParentId` of 5 being grouped under `null`.

Is this some type of bug with EF or am I just missing something here?  BTW I'm using EF 6.1.3.

Comment: what is parentid ? is it dashboardid? ie. parent of the row? does dashboardrow id = 5 exist?

Comment: @Thorarins `ParentId` is a link to the `CurrentId`.  So the third row is the child of the second.  And the fifth row should be a child of the first row, not a top level parent.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is caused by a non-unique primary key (as EF knows it) in the view.

Comment: @GertArnold That makes sense as the entity is setup such that the Key is basically all the rows except for `ParentId` because it can be `null`.  I guess I could try to figure out a way to make my View include some type of unique value for each row and see if that fixes the issue.  Or maybe just have top level Parent ids be 0 or -1.

Comment: If @GertArnold 's comment helped, he could post an answer, of if he doesn't, you could, juharr, and accept the answer. I think this could be helpful to others.

Comment: Seems like some issue with entityKey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a **non-unique primary key**. Your query is fine.

I noticed that the row in question (#5) matches almost completely with row #2. I reckon you have a composite key of some / all of the columns except 'ParentId'.

```
         DashboardId     CurrentId  Type  Name       ParentId
Row #2   4               6          2     Market     NULL
Row #5   4               6          2     Market     5
```

For whatever reason Entity framework is more strict about upholding those rules than sql server is when *rendering* the data.

What you need to do is **make sure your data has integrity**.Otherwise Entity framework, or any other ORM might cause unexpected problems.