# Linq to Entities strange results

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following View in my database

```
SELECT  YEAR(Received) AS YEAR, 
        MONTH(Received) AS MONTH, 
        LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, Received), 3) AS MMM, 
        COUNT(Received) AS Submissions, 
        COUNT(Quoted) AS Quotes, 
        COUNT(Bound) AS Binders, 
        COALESCE (SUM(BndPremium), 0) AS Premium, 
        ProducerID
  FROM  dbo.Quote AS Q WITH (NOLOCK)
  WHERE (Received >= DATEADD(year, - 1, GETDATE()))
  GROUP BY ProducerID, YEAR(Received), MONTH(Received), DATENAME(MONTH, Received)
```

And I have added the view to my EDMX. I query the view this way:

```
var submissions = from s in db.WSS_PortalSubmissions
                  where s.ProducerID == ID
                  select s;
```

The results in 'submissions' however, is 12 copies of the first month rather than the results from the past 12 months.  Running the query in Linq today I get 12 copies of the results from April 2016. If I run the query in SSMS I get the expected results, a list of the last 12 months.

I have tried .ToList(), .ToArray(), even tried some sorting of the results, but it doesn't change. It is only giving me 12 copies of the first month. Any reasons why that I can't see?

Comment: I've learned that EF doesn't play well with Views because it really wants a key for the entity and in the case of a View it will just use all non-nullable columns which can lead to odd results.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889910/ef-returning-different-values-than-query

Comment: @juharr - unless you map it like you would a table and specify a primary key column(s) that make a record unique.

Comment: I would change the view so that there is a unique column(s) if there is not one already and make sure it is mapped as the primary key in EF. If that is not an option try changing the code to `b.WSS_PortalSubmissions.AsNoTracking()` so that EF does not track the entity, this should force it to just return exactly the results of the query without trying to track based on a primary key.

Comment: @Igor AsNoTracking() worked perfect for me. I had completely forgotten about the primary key issue with EF (been out of practice for almost a year).

Comment: @Marc - glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the view so that there is a unique column(s) if there is not one already and make sure it is mapped as the primary key in EF.

If that is not an option try changing the code to

```
var submissions = from s in db.WSS_PortalSubmissions.AsNoTracking()
       where s.ProducerID == ID
       select s;
```

so that EF does not track the entity, this should force it to just return exactly the results of the query without trying to track based on a primary key.